# How to capture data and use the same in load runner?

Tags: loadrunner

I'll explain the scenario i'm trying to test.

> screen x : Enter a order, Capture the order number.
>   screen y : Enter the captured order number and approve it.

My Steps:

Using Vugen i had recorded and replayed it the response message contains order number. And i am not aware on how to capture it. this is for one record, if i were doing the same using controller with 40 users, i need all the order numbers to be captured, and use the same in screen y to approve it.

Please let me know who to achieve it? Also what is the best way to test it, i mean the flow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See training material: Subject Correlation.  This is the topic for a full 1/3 of the training class.  if you have not been through training and are not operating in an internship with a senior fellow to guide you then you need to speak immediately to your management about this lack of support as you are being set up to fail.